# Sizeof Struct vs Sizeof Type

Tags: c

Im not "that" new to C but can some one please enlighten me on this one:

```
printf( "%d %d\n", sizeof( int ), sizeof( unsigned char ) );
```

print as expected 4 and 1.

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    unsigned char b;
} test

printf( "%d\n", sizeof( test ) );
```

print 8... Im really confused!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Data_structure_padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called "[alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)". Your `struct` is padded. You can "[pack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)" it (different compilers have different ways of defining which type should be packed), and then it won't be aligned, but you might have run-time data access issues.

Comment: Would you recommend to always pack data at 1 byte to optimize the size or use the compiler default for performance purposes?

Comment: @McBob, no, on the contrary, never pack unless you're certain that you need it and you know exactly what you're doing. Compiler is using the system-default values which when ignored might degrade performance and on some systems cause crashes.

Comment: Im working on a network protocol and the header size of each protocol command should be static, in this case I should insure that the size will remain the same on every platform right? So in this case I should use packing for the header structure right?

Comment: @McBob networking is a notable exception to the above rule. Usually - that's the most common place where you **would** pack. Note that accessing packed struct might be problematic, and you should use byte pointers (char*) to access any member.